# Helm says 404 when trying to add Gitlab registry

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the Community edition of Gitlab. Now, with 14.1 I also want use the Helm registry. Everything works fine, I can push my helm package to the helm package registry, download the tgz and so on, but when I use

`helm repo add --username "<my-username>" --password "<access-token>" helm-chart https://gitlab.somedomain.tld/api/v4/projects/265/packages/helm/api/stable/charts`

It says

> Error: looks like "https://gitlab.somedomain.tld/api/v4/projects/265/packages/helm/api/stable/charts" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://gitlab.somedomain.tld/api/v4/projects/265/packages/helm/api/stable/charts/index.yaml : 404 Not Found

I already checked the project-id (265) but it's correct and I also push my chart to

`curl --request POST --user gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN --form "chart=@$PACKAGE_FILE" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/helm/api/stable/charts"`

So I wonder what's going wrong here. I can push to the helm registry but cannot retrieve/find the index.yaml. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Try to find index.yaml file there: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/helm/stable/index.yaml

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.